# how to convert value into Indian rupees format?

Tags: angular, ionic3

i am getting value from the array and i need to convert that value into indian rupee format?

```
                    <h3>
                        <ion-icon ios="ios-cash" md="md-cash"></ion-icon>{{user.members}} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;/&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ₹ {{user.total | currency:"₹":0}}
                    </h3>
```

Expected
I need value as 1,95,445.76,
Actual Output
195,445.76

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe), you should be using this instead:

```
{{user.total | currency: 'INR'}}
```

I think the format you used above is for AngularJS (Angular 1.x).

---

EDIT: I notice that the above format does not take the Indian numeric system into account. Hence, here is my updated solution. I wrote a custom method that makes use of JavaScript's [.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) .

```
indianRupeeFormat(val: number) {
  return Number(val).toLocaleString('en-IN');
}
```

And this is how it will be displayed on your view:

```
<p>Rupee:₹ {{ indianRupeeFormat(195445.76) }}</p>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-currency-pipe-xubkkh?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks it worked fine, and i may need another help, how can i remove the values after the decimal point ??

Comment: @stephen Glad to help. Just to clarify, do you want it to be rounded up?

Comment: yeaa exactly @wentjun

Comment: @stephen You can use `Math.round()` for that purpose. I guess you can change the above to `Math.round(Number(val)).toLocaleString('en-IN');`?

Comment: What if the value was in loop? Is there any method to get solution with HTML ?

Comment: @stephen in a loop? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: The value in an array and i need to bind the value in HTML using NgFor loop so how could i convert that particular value into round-off

Comment: @stephen you can use decimal pipe (https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe). For example, `{{ 195445.76 | number:'1.0-0' }}` will round it up.

Answer (score 0):

use built in pipes

```
  <h3 <ion-icon ios="ios-cash" md="md-cash"></ion-icon>{{user.members}} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;/&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ₹ {{user.total | currency:"INR":0}}
```